# Fetch core data object where to-many relationship contains all objects in a set

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

What I'm looking for is a succinct way to fetch a core-data object that is identified uniquely by its relationships. e.g., given the data model:

[image]

... and given a set of `NSManagedObject` nodes, I'd like to fetch a triangle, or at least know if a TriangleEntity exists like so:

```
NSSet *nodeSet = // a set of 3 NSManagedObject*s
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"TriangleEntity"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"corners CONTAINS ALL %@", nodeSet];
```

I don't think that `CONTAINS ALL` is proper syntax -- And I know that I could just unpack the NSSet and fetch

```
@"corners CONTAINS %@ AND corners CONTAINS %@ AND corners CONTAINS %@", setObj1, setObj2, setObj3
```

... but that seems silly. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following predicate finds triangles where all corners are in the given set:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL corners IN %@", nodeSet]
```

`nodeSet` can be an `NSSet` or an `NSArray`.

Comment: beautiful. can you point to the apple docs for reference? or is this just the voice of experience?

Comment: @SamHatchett: "ALL" and "IN" are documented in [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB) in the "Predicate Programming Guide". How to combine these correctly is a matter of experience in my case.

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "ALL contacts IN %@", selectedContacts)` results in crash with "Unsupported predicate" in console. `selectedContacts` is a Swift Array of NSManagedObjects. This is also a many-to-many relationship. Any ideas?

Comment: @hgwhittle same here. do you have any solutions so far?